# Sencha Touch - hasParent() returns false; getParent() returns undefined; on component that has a parent

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a simple view that has a list on the left and a container to show details of the tapped list item on the right defined as such:

```
Ext.define('app.view.activity.ListContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.activitylistcontainer',
    requires: [
        'app.view.activity.List',
        'app.view.activity.ListDetail'
    ],
    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'activitylist',
                flex: 4
            },
            {
                xtype: 'activitylistdetail',
                flex: 5
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

When the `activity.List` Store loads, I want `activity.ListDetail` to show the details of the first Record in the Store. My problem is that I cannot get to `activity.ListContainer` because it is not being recognised as the parent of `activity.List`.

```
onActivityListInitialize: function(component, options){
    var activityStore = Ext.create('app.store.Activity');

    activityStore.on('load', function(store, records, successful, operation, eOpts){
        var activityListHasContainer = component.hasParent(),
            activityListContainer = component.getParent(),
            activityListContainerUp = component.up('activitylistcontainer');
        console.log(component, component.parent, activityListHasContainer, activityListContainer, activityListContainerUp);
    });

    component.setStore(activityStore);
}
```

The output of the `console.log` is `Object, undefined, false, undefined, undefined`. I included `component.parent` in the `log` because when I inspect the object there is a `parent` property, but for whatever reason it shows `undefined` when `log`ged out.

Could someone help shed some light on this? Is `activity.ListContainer` not considered a parent of `activity.List` in Sencha? Or is it something else in my app that is screwing with this? If it helps, `activity.ListContainer` is inside a `navigationview`

Comment: getParent is method to get base class of object. Try property component.isContained, recently I used it, but today I can't find documentation for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `activity.ListContainer` does not exist at the time the `activity.ActivityList initialize` event is triggered. My solution is to move this method to the `activity.ListContainer initialize` event.